# C# Error send emails using gmail or hotmail

Tags: c#, sockets, gmail, hotmail

in my application i need to send Emails by C# (Using Gmail or Hotmail)
on localhost it's working ok no error but when upload to Godaddy hosting all the time i have error like

**Hotmail:**
**Code:**

```html
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@hotmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(ReciverMail);
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;
            htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";
            mail.Body = htmlBody;
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx@outlook.com", "xxxxx");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

            return "Mail has been successfully sent!";
```

**Error:**
[image]

**Gmail: 
Code:**

```html
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress("xxx", "xxxx");
            msg.Subject = "From ASU  at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            msg.To.Add(ReciverMail);
            msg.Body = "Test";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
            client.Timeout = 20000;
           
            client.Send(msg);
            return "Mail has been successfully sent!";
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that your Godaddy hosting firewall is allowing outbound traffic and that you are not being blocked by antivirus software.

Basically windows Firewall is creat this error. SMTP was trying to post to GMAIL and Hotmail at port 587. Adding port 587 to the Outbound rule [Outbound HTTP/SMTP/RDP] will resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) , i didn't find any option related with firewall if Plesk Control panel.